# add a incremental counter using react app ++ operators not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, increment

i am tryign to write method for voting everytime user click button it should increment by 1 it is happening with below code

retro.js

```
  export class RetroComponent extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.textareaRef = React.createRef();
        this.state = {
          value: 0
        }
      }
      addCard(){
        console.log("add card");
      }
      incrementWentWell() {
        // eslint-disable-next-line react/no-direct-mutation-state
        return ++this.state.value;
      }
    render() {
          return (
        <IconButton onClick={() => this.incrementWentWell()}>
                      <ThumbUpTwoToneIcon />
                    </IconButton>
       <h5 style={{marginRight: 10}}><p>{this.state.value}</p></h5>
    )}
    }
```

Comment: You have specifically disabled the ESlint rule that tells you what the problem is. https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/no-direct-mutation-state.md

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That *still* counts as a state mutation (*huge anti-pattern!*). Ignoring the warning doesn't make the behavior change. Use a functional state update to take the existing state value, add 1 to it, and return a new state object so react can reconcile the change and update the UI/DOM.

```
incrementWentWell() {
  this.setState(state => ({ value: state.value + 1 })
}
```

[image: Edit react - class-based regular and functional state updates]